# Confusing my IP stack

Tags: networking, oracle-database

At work, I have an Oracle GRID/RAC cluster of two hosts, including Oracle's SCAN functionality. Picking one host: `eth0` is the management port on `169.254.10.25`. `eth1`, `eth2`, and `eth3` comprise `bondeth0` (because that's not confusing o_O). It has its bond IP address `169.254.30.61`, and one or two of the SCAN IP addresses, `169.254.30.71`, `.72`, and/or `.73` as virtual IP addresses.

Clear as mud?

Now, I have this second host with a single interface, on `169.254.10.80`. If I ping `10.25` from there, I get responses. If I ping `30.61`, I get responses. If I ping any of the SCAN addresses, my sniffer sees the ping arrive, but I never get a response.

If I repeat the test from another host on an entirely different subnet, I get responses from `10.25`, `10.80`, `30.61`, `30.71`, and `30.73`. (`30.72` was on the other host in the GRID/RAC cluster.)

My inclination is that the host is getting a ping request to, say, `30.71`, on the bonded interface and tries to send its reply along `eth0`. Somewhere along the way, that fails. So far, I haven't figured out how to test and verify that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the subnet of all these interfaces (are they all really `/16` or `255.255.0.0`?)  What's the "entirely different subnet" you are pinging from?  If this is a Linux system, the output if `ip addr show` would be helpful.  It sounds like there is a problem with the subnet addresses assigned off the top of my head.

Comment: The addresses and (implied) subnetting were deliberately obfuscated, as I was discussing a work system. I think the solution turned out to be a change in the Oracle configuration.